Is there any way to totally hide TabViewItem element in Xamarin.Forms?
I have simple TabView control and want to hide 'Tab 2' of the TabViewItem element.
The tab 2 was hidden by setting IsVisible="false" property, but I expect that only 2 tabs will remain in the view.
Is there any way to remove the empty space between 'tab 1' and 'tab 3'?
I can't just remove 'tab 2', because it will be used in some cases under certain conditions.
In addition, I've noticed that hiding the 'tab 2' breaks the tab indicator's behavior for 'tab 3', because there is no yellow line above the tab.
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App1.Views.AboutPage"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModels"
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         Title="{Binding Title}">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:AboutViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <xct:TabView    TabStripPlacement="Top" 
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            TabStripBackgroundColor="Blue"
                            IsTabStripVisible="True"
                            TabIndicatorColor="Yellow"
                            TabIndicatorPlacement="Top"
                            SelectedIndex="0"
                            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                            x:Name="TabViewBox"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

                <xct:TabViewItem Text="Tab 1" TextColor="White" TextColorSelected="Yellow">
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray">
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="TabContent1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </xct:TabViewItem>
                <xct:TabViewItem Text="Tab 2" TextColor="White" TextColorSelected="Yellow"  IsVisible="false">
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="TabContent2" />
                    </Grid>
                </xct:TabViewItem>

                <xct:TabViewItem x:Name="NewBoxes1Tab" Text="Tab 3" TextColor="White" TextColorSelected="Yellow">
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="TabContent3" />
                    </Grid>
                </xct:TabViewItem>
                
            </xct:TabView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>



